# Web API Custom method with [FromBody] parameter, called via DataServiceContext.Execute

Tags: .net, client, odata, asp.net-web-api

On the service side I have a pretty simple config, that works fine when passing parameter via URL:

(snippet)

```
builder.EntitySet<MappedAuthorizationGroup>("MappedAuthorizationGroups");
var function = builder.Function("TestMethod");
//parameter removed here, because I want to POST it ([FromBody])
//function.Parameter<string>("id"); 
function.ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<MappedAuthorizationGroup>("MappedAuthorizationGroups");
```

The controller method decoration again is fairly simple:

```
[HttpPost]
[ODataRoute("TestMethod")]  //(id={id})")]  // Again, parameter removed because i want to POST it
public IQueryable<MappedAuthorizationGroup> TestMethod([FromBody]string id)
{
    ... code ...
}
```

Now, there's several answers here regarding how to call this via AJAX, but I'm already using the microsoft odata client  (DataServiceContext) for all the "normal" Odata calls (CRUD operations)...so I'd like to use it for these custom calls as well (using .Execute(), I assume?)

My very simplied client code:

```
var client = new Default.Container(new Uri("thecorrectURI"));

var methodURI = new Uri(client.BaseUri, "TestMethod");   

var recs = client.Execute<MappedAuthorizationGroup>(methodURI, "POST", new BodyOperationParameter("id", "C26DFAF6-8F32-429B-9DB3-2F8CF0ABBD3A"));
```

However, this does not correctly populate the string "id" parameter that should be [FromBody] when it reaches the server.  After investigating this seems to be because of 1 or 2 reasons:

1. The content-type is wrong.  However, if I set the content type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"  I get a different error on the server, because it is expecting json, which I think should be fine for only a single, primitive parameter.
2. BodyOperationParameter() serialzes to JSON, but this for some reason does not work on the server side.  Many posts mention that it's only compatible with the simple "=myvalue" passing.  Is this correct?  How do I do this from the DataServiceContext object?  Will I have to make this call from something more general, like a HttpClient object, where it's very easy to set the correct headers and body content?

The reason I want to move this to the body rather than a simple URL, is this parameter is actually going to be a serialized list of GUIDs, quite possibly more than should be set in a URL.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, quite a few things to resolve this.  Each one was documented "somewhere" on the web, but none of them really came together in a single solution that I could use in this scenario (which seems like it should be awfully common...hmm).  Anyway:

The method decoration was correct on the odata controller side, as :

```
[HttpPost]
[ODataRoute("TestMethod")]
public IQueryable<YourEntity> TestMethod([FromBody]string id)
```

(I kept parameter name as "id" to eliminate the need to create another route)

On the client/consumer side, quite a bit had to change from my original code.  Firstly, I couldn't use the odata client context stuff, as it doesn't give you enough control over the parameter serialization, which is a problem.  Also, it seemed to only want to send JSON, and setting the content-type to something else (for a form post), caused another error.  Probably because our OData service typically works with JSON for all the standard CRUD calls, and there doesn't seem to be a clean way to say "only expect non-JSON data for certain custom calls").  At the same time, serializing body content parameters to JSON does not work.

So, going with HttpClient gave more control with the request.  however the request body content was very particular with the format.  I *had* to send it as "=stringvalue", UTF-8 encoding.

Getting the data back was also an issue, as the IEnumerable seems to come back wrapped in a "value" object...so deserializing the response JSON to List would fail.  Creating a class with a single List property called "value", and deserializing to this object, FINALLY succeeded.

Final client-side code to actually get this working (for me) looks a bit like:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/mywebsite/odata");

    // Content string *MUST* start with =
    var content = new StringContent("=C26DFAF6-8F32-429B-9DB3-2F8CF0ABBD3A", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost/mywebsite/odata/TestMethod");
    message.Content = content;

    // Send the request
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(message).Result;

    // Get the result
    string retval = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    // Deserialize the response
    var jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    var groups = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<TestContainer>(retval);
}
```

And the dummy "container" used to aid in deserialization:

```
public class TestContainer
{
    public List<YourModel> value    { get; set; }
}
```